# Bash syntax error in for loop

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, syntax

I have a list of files like this "file1.stream_2015-02-17.mp4" that I have been deleting by time using this

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTENT_DIR=/my_files/recordings
find $CONTENT_DIR -mtime +1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[.](mp4|tmp)$' -delete
```

That has been working fine for me so far but now I am trying to delete all the ones with file1.stream by 1 day and all the ones with file2.stream by 7 days

I have been trying this but I mainly keep coming up with errors

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTENT_DIR=/my_files/recordings/*

for f in $CONTENT_DIR; do
  if [[ -f ${f} =~ 'file1.stream_*' ]] then
    find -mtime +7 ${f} -delete
  else
    find -mtime +1 ${f} -delete
  fi
done
```

but I keep getting this error

```
syntax error in conditional expression 
syntax error near `=~'
`   if [[ -f ${f} =~ 'file1.stream_*' ]] then'
```

I am not sure what the error is and I have been looking around for a few hours trying to find the syntax error. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be contaminating two different constructs.  You need to check them both separately.

`[[ -f "$f" ]]` checks whether the file `$f` exists and is a regular file.

`[[ "$f" =~ regex ]]` checks if the string in `$f` matches the regular expression `regex`.

You can combine them like this:

```
if [[ -f "$f" && "$f" =~ regex ]]; then ...
```

or simply break it up into two separate comparisons:

```
if [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ "$f" =~ regex ]]; then ...
```

Notice also the required semicolon (or newline) before `then`.

But the pattern you have is a glob pattern, not a regex, so you probably want to use a glob comparison instead.

Additionally, your string is not a valid argument to `find` -- I suppose you really mean

```
if ...; then
    find -mtime +7 -name "$f" -delete
: etc
```

or perhaps (somewhat equivalently, in this context)

```
if ...; then
    find "$f" -mtime +7 -delete
: etc
```

where the argument definitely needs to be in double quotes, otherwise the shell will perform wildcard expansion on it and replace the variable with the expanded results, producing yet another syntax error.

Finally, it's not particularly good form to put the pattern in a variable and then use it unquoted.  The variable seems to serve no useful purpose, so just inline the pattern into the `for` loop.

```
for f in /my_files/recordings/*; do
  if [[ -f "$f" && "$f" == 'file1.stream_'* ]]; then
    find -mtime +7 -name "$f" -delete
  else
    find -mtime +1 -name "$f" -delete
  fi
done
```

... or even just decide the `mtime` parameter inside the conditional.

```
for f in /my_files/recordings/*; do
  if [[ -f "$f" && "$f" == 'file1.stream_'* ]]; then
    mtime=+7
  else
    mtime=+1
  fi
  find -mtime "$mtime" -name "$f" -delete
done
```

Comment: I haven't read the question thoroughly, but wouldn't: `find /my_files/recordings \( -name '*file1.stream*' -mtime +7 -o -name '*file2.stream*' -mtime +1 \) -delete` be enough? Also, the `_*` in the regex is highly useless and the period should be escaped.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I didn't realise I was mixing the two constructs, I had looked at too many different Q&A's and had mixed everything up. I don't need to be checking if the file exists so I have removed it and just gone with regex

Comment: Actually I wholeheartedly second @gniourf_gniourf's improvement to only run a single `find`.  It might need a minor change (the `*file2.stream` placeholder most likely needs to be adapted to the file names you are really working with) but it's much better.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your `if` condition and `=~` is used for regex only.

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /my_files/recordings/*; do
  if [[ -f "$f" && "$f" == 'file1.stream_'* ]]; then
    find "$f" -mtime +7 -delete
  else
    find "$f" -mtime +1 -delete
  fi
done
```

Also glob pattern needs to be outside quote as shown in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do two things at once; check if a file (`$f`) exists and is a regular file, and attempting to compare the result of that test (which is a return code, not text) with the regex you've given (which also looks like it's using a glob instead of a regex pattern match). Combining the two is also not allowed here. The `then` is another (built-in) command, you'll need to separate it from the `if` ... part.

Split the check into the parts it should be, and either use glob matching, or use a regex, eg.:

```
if [[ -f "${f}" && "${f}" == file1.stream_* ]]; then ...; fi
```

... or, for regex matching:

```
if [[ -f "${f}" && "${f}" =~ file1\.stream_.* ]]; then ...; fi
```

Also note that the regex match does not anchor to the beginning and end and so, unlike the glob match, is effectively the same as `^.*file1\.stream.*$`.

Comment: Your statement: _Don't quote the match string, the quotes will be included in the match and be expected to exist themselves!_ is just plain wrong.